# Where will Gargoyles spawn on Halloween Maps?

Tags: team-fortress-2

With the annual seasonal event kicking off, where will the Gargoyles spawn for each Halloween map?

Comment: According to a few reports gargoyles spawn in the same places as the old '[Haunted Halloween Gifts](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Haunted_Halloween_Gift)', however, I've noticed different spawn locations on their listed maps (I've seen them spawn next to the payload elevators on Helltower for example), so I don't think this 100% covers it

Answer (score 2):

[Courtesy of the TF2 Wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Soul_Gargoyle#Ghost_Gargoyle_spawn_locations), below are images of the Soul Gargoyle spawn locations.

Note that the Gargoyle locations are marked with gift icons, as the Gargoyles replaced [Halloween Gifts](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Haunted_Halloween_Gift) in 2015. The list is also not comprehensive, as some maps (such as [Terror](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Terror)) are not included.

#### Mann Manor

[image: Mann Manor locations]

#### Eyeaduct

[image]

[image]

#### Ghost Fort

[image]

#### Moonshine Event

[image]

#### Gravestone

[image]

#### Helltower

[image]

#### Crasher

[image]

#### Helltrain

[image]

#### Bonesaw

[image]

#### Soul-Mill

[image]

#### Terror

Has two spawn locations in the center of the map. (Added [October 8, 2021](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/October_8,_2021_Patch)). [Shown in this video by LED](https://youtu.be/hWTrb_MGI9k?t=52).

---

#### Sources

- [Team Fortress 2 Wiki - Soul Gargoyle](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Soul_Gargoyle)
- [LED (YouTube) - NEVER miss another Gargoyle!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWTrb_MGI9k)